# Performance Issues loading large data set into c# GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Ok,

been testing relatively small data sets into my GridView, and all has worked fine. However, i've now moved into proper UAT and have tried to load 17,000 records into my Grid, which has basically brought my web app to a grinding halt.

Basically, a user logs in, and upon validation all the data grids are loaded, one of which contains 17k records. Until everything loads the end user is left handing on the logon page. So i need to fix it.

The code for the Grids is:

```
DataTable dtValueDateCurrency = null;               
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Reporting"].ConnectionString);
using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    //Load all other grid data
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(TSQL1, conn))
    {
        dtValueDateSummary = new DataTable();
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dtValueDateSummary);
        grdValueDateSummary.DataSource = dtValueDateSummary;
        grdValueDateSummary.DataBind();
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to increase the load times? Pagination isn't an option, as i'm taking care of this with JQuery.

Comment: Don't load 17k records from database but use database paging(e.g. via `ROW_NUMBER` function). Don't DataBind so many records to your `GridView` but use serverside-paging instead of jquery. Have you looked at the generated HTML? Then you would know why it's slow.

Comment: `Performance Issues loading large data set into c# GridView` == "Don't load large data set into c# GridView"

Comment: You might get slightly better response from adding records from the database via a datareader instead of a data adapter. I understand that it is better for large datasets. Basically you would fill the datatable manually... you will still take a hit when it hits gridview.bind()

Comment: Based on your comments to the answers here, let me be more general: do not try to load 17,000 records of anything on the web, ever. This isn't a `GridView` problem. This isn't a `DataReader` vs. `DataAdapter` problem. This is just too much information for one page. This has to happen on the server. You will have to change your paging and your filtering options to work a different way, but they will still work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

loading 17,000 records in one query is what's killing you. I highly suggest paging your gridview.

First you need to alter your Stored Procedure as follows.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeTable_GetPagedResults] 
( 
        @StartRowIndex      int, 
        @MaximumRows        int 
) 

AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

Select 
    RowNum, 
    [ID], 
    [foo],
    [bar]
From 
    (Select 
        [ID], 
        [foo], 
        [bar], 
        Row_Number() Over(Order By [ID] Desc) As RowNum 
        From dbo.[SomeTable] t) 
As DerivedTableName 
Where RowNum Between @StartRowIndex And (@StartRowIndex + @MaximumRows)
```

Now you have a pageable query.

You also want a query to get the complete row count.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeTable_GetRowCount] 

AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

return (Select Count(ID) As TotalRecords From SomeTable)
```

You'll bind your grid every time you change the page.

```csharp
protected void gridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  gridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  BindGrid(); // this is whatever method you call to bind your data and execute your stored procedure.
}
```

And the `BindGrid()` method will call your two stored procedures (one to get the complete row count, and one to get the results pertaining to your current page)

[Additional Reading](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/gridview-paging-sample-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: Ok, gret for the quick respones, but i don't want to use Pagination. The JQuery code allows drag and drop of cols, real time filtering without db calls, so needs to stay. Is there a way of showing 500 records, then allowing the user to view these whilst the rest is loaded?

Comment: why can't you do both? You can't seriously be showing ALL 17000 records on a single page. Who's going to drag and drop anything in that mess? I seriously believe you need to re-think your approach.

Comment: Chase, i restrict the page to only show 20 records per page, but the rest is there all the time, for real time filtering. So, even if an item is on page 300, the grid is isntantly filetered to only show that record

Comment: I feel this is a bad approach. The better approach would simply be to make an ajax call to the server with the filter requirements. Feed those back to the app with pagination enabled.

Comment: I've written a blog post on this exact requirement. I'm going to try and dig it up and pass it along.

Comment: This answer is still retrieving all 17,000 records in each call, except now it's only showing a page-worth of data.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I'm working on a more exhaustive answer. The example is incomplete, but the approach is sound.

Comment: I guess, a question I need to ask myself, is do i need a GridView at all? Would i still hit the same performance issues, if I built a HTML page on the fly? This was the prime reason for using a GridView, to produce the HTML, so Jquery could do it's magic

Comment: You could switch to a Repeater, but it's definitely the data, not the markup, that's bogging things down.

Comment: @Garrison, i think i may have to bow down and admit defeat on this, and do pagination on a GridView.... :-(

Comment: Keep in mind that by default, GridView's out-of-the-box pagination will speed up the render of the page, but it will still pull 17,000 rows with each page request.  What it does is it calls your function, and if you're on page 1, shows the first x items (based on how you set it).  If you move to page 2, it pulls 17,000 more rows, then it throws away the first x, displays the next x.  This continues.  If your query is returning 17,000 rows quickly, this solution will work.  If not, this solution won't work.  Test out by putting a breakpoint in your code before and after the call, then see time.

Comment: SQL execution plan returns 17000 records in 1 sec, so its an issue with the drawing of each row (painting i believe it's called). This needs some thinking about, and decisions to be made when on a nights sleep. thanks for your comments guys, i will report back and mark accordingly once i've processed this info

Comment: I don't want to belabor the point, but .NET still has to process those records into objects in memory, and that may not necessarily take 1-2 seconds.  You've got the code and you can test it, though, so I defer to you on that point.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell will definately give this a shot in the morning. Appreciate the help

Comment: @CSharpNewBee  Well as you dont want to use paging on server side , You may have two choices you can keep dataset stored in session which i do not support another way is caching you can cache dataset which is also very costly for server memory  , one more thin you can do is use SQLdatasource control caching  , It will save you round trips to server which will increase your response time ,However if your data changes in back end but still your grid will be fetched old data from cache however this issue also can be solved using SQL Cache dependency . So review all your options !!!

Comment: @CSharpNewBee regarding the `1 sec` return. That is on the server. The server then needs to pass the 17000 row model over the wire to the client... that's your slowdown. Even pushing the data as JSON would take a long time. Internet transfer speeds aren't designed for such large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

You need to institute database paging.

This will involve creating custom sorting, custom filtering, and custom paging, but it will dramatically increase the performance of your code, as you'll be retrieving only a pages-worth of data at a time from the DB, instead of all 17,000 rows at a time.

I implemented this in a banking application that was designed to show, sort, and filter hundreds of thousands of loans.  The answer is too complicated to give a simple example for, but start by researching database paging.  Use LINQ, it'll give you simple `Take` and `Skip` methods to implement the paging easiest.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into caching the query on the web server, especially if it's infrequently updated. That way, all the clients can simply surf off the cache instead of hitting the database mercilessly.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793746/cache-results-from-sql-database-or-query-each-time)

Comment: this doesn't address the initial call to the 17000 records. breaking up the request (paging/lazy loading) is the ONLY WAY to solve this issue.

Comment: He could have it load into cache on Application_Start.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely there's a thought

Comment: Indeed, sorry I wasn't more specific about loading it into the cache on Applicaton_Start. Another part of the equation would be dealing with stale data -- you'll have to figure out when your web server should update the cache. There's a lot to do!

Comment: not to mention that as soon as he uses his jquery drag/drop, the cache will need to be fully updated to reflect the changes.

Comment: I'm afraid he can't have it both ways -- sticking to jquery to manage the dataset as a whole and being able to do the fancy queries.

Comment: You can if you're using jquery to simple make ajax calls to the server.

Comment: @JesseSmith may well have to revert to one method or another, as this needs to be complete by COB Friday. Some late nights ahead :-)

Answer (score 0):

Really, loading a 17k record once is not useful even user can not see the whole 17k records at once. I would suggest you to use pagination along with `DataTable.Merge` function which helps to load records in chunks and append the new fetched data into previous one. I just did a quick test and found a solution. [Give this a try.](http://shahanayyub.wordpress.com/2014/03/30/how-to-load-large-dataset-in-datagridview/)

Answer (score -1):

There is not solution pagination is slow and will call database again and again,
So you need to
put

```
<style>.body{display:none;}</style>
```

start of the page
and at the end of the page

```
<style>.body{display:block;}</style>
```