# C# Data GridView, large data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

We are having the same issue as the one here
[Performance Issues loading large data set into c# GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979498/performance-issues-loading-large-data-set-into-c-sharp-gridview)
Tried to implement the solution provided by "Chase Florell".
In the 1st stored Procedure i am setting @MaximumRows to 100 and also my gridview Pagesize is also 100.
So it is fetching 100 records and displaying 100 records so i dont see any pagination (1st issue).

### And not able to understand where the value for "TotalRecords" is been used?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to run a separate query to get your total rows, and then use that to build your pager.

Comment: TotalRecords is to know how many the overall query would normally return, since the main select will return only whatever the size of your page is, you have no idea how big it would be unless you do it that way, and then with this you can build your pagination (dividing the total by the page size i.e.)

Comment: Total record count is part of the formula for determining how many pages of data the grid has; `Total record count / records per page = number of pages`. You need to know this to properly make your paging controls on the screen for the user to navigate through the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Efficiently Paging Through Large Amounts of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445510.aspx) for a walkthrough of setting up custom paging with a `GridView` control.

You will need to have a separate query for the total record count, which should be done first.

Then you can calculate the number of pages the grid will have in order to build the paging controls.

```
Total record count / records per page = number of pages
```

Note: the `records per page` may be hard-coded in the `GridView` markup or you can have a control on your page that allows the user to pick a page size.