# Long response time for loading a grid view from a table in oracle database

Tags: oracle, gridview, datagridview, plsql, sys-refcursor

I am working on Web Application using .Net 4.5 Framework. I am populating a grid view from a table in oracle database. The table is huge with almost 73,000 records and each with 5 columns. The response time for loading of the table is around 4 mins.I am currently populating with help of Connected architecture method of ADO.Net. I want a way to reduce the response time.

The code for retrieving

```
 public DataTable RetrieveManufacturerDetails() {
    try {
      OpenDBConnection();
      objDataTable = new DataTable();
      objTrans = objCon.BeginTransaction();
      objCommand = new OracleCommand("SP_GET_MANUFACTURER_DETAILS", objCon);
      objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      objCommand.Parameters.Add("cManufacturer", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      objCommand.Transaction = objTrans;
      objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = objCommand;
      objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataTable);
      objTrans.Commit();
      return objDataTable;
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
      objTrans.Rollback();
      throw Ex;
    } finally {
      objCommand.Dispose();
      objCon.Close();
    }
  }
```

The stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GET_MANUFACTURER_DETAILS(cManufacturer OUT sys_refcursor )
AS
BEGIN

  OPEN cManufacturer 
  FOR
  SELECT MANUFACTURE_CODE AS "Manufcode", 
         MANUFACTURE_NAME AS "Manufname", 
         VENDOR_ACCOUNT_GROUP AS "Ktokk", 
         CITY AS "City", 
         POST_CODE AS "Postcode" 
   FROM MATERIAL_MANUFACTURE_INFO ;

END SP_GET_MANUFACTURER_DETAILS;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code and explain the database structure? Is the query searching using indexed fields, for example?

Comment: 73k records with 5 columns is not huge for oracle, as @GrandMasterFlush says, table defs, code etc.

Comment: Perhaps try not loading all 73k at once, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979498/performance-issues-loading-large-data-set-into-c-sharp-gridview) for some ideas.

Comment: I have added the code  and stored procedure above. Sorry its not aligned properly

Comment: First thing to check is if the delay is in the database query, datatable filling or the adding of the datatable contents to your grid view. I suspect it is the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is the delay in adding 73k rows to your data grid view, not in the database retrieval.

With that many results you will need to implement the virtual mode grid view. This means it only loads the results that you can see.

Check this link with a simple implementation.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23937/Paging-Data-with-DataGridView-in-VirtualMode