# Caching Query Results vs Querying Each Time

Tags: sql-server, performance, caching

This is kind of an expansion on [a previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793746/cache-results-from-sql-database-or-query-each-time)

Some background info:

```
Querying Over 5,000 items from SQL database that eventually get sorted into a list depending on who the user is. 
One problem is that users are allowed to have customized lists which means that sorting these 5,000+ items in a uniform way is probably impossible.

Also, important that the amount of users (and users wanting to have custom item lists) is constantly growing, so there will be an unprecedented amount of ways to sort. Basically, we won't be paying attention to sorting this growing list.

Two methods we've come up with so far:
-Option 1: Cache item list PER USER (and sort the items needed after)
OR
-Option 2: Cache the list once for the whole site (every user accesses this one cached list)

The issue with Option 1 is that there will be duplicated lists in cache.
Although we do not have an amount of users that will strain our server's memory, we obviously want our system to have scalability.

The issue with Option 2 is that there will be duplicated items in the single, cached list.
With the amount of users we have, this can quickly turn into a disorganized list full of duplicated items (i.e. 5,000 items can quickly turn into 10,000 based on a few user's custom item preferences)
```

Is there a "middle ground" for dealing with this situation? One that combines some benefits of querying and caching.

Even if a response is a link to a potentially helpful source, I would appreciate it as I am kind of at a fork in the road.

Looking to open up new possible paths in my brainstorming.

Also, looking for suggestions on how to improve this question if it makes no sense at all.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: ** By sorting, I mean FILTERING. I apologize for some confusion regarding this.

Comment: If you use static data, you can load the data into one list and create a list of pointers for each user which can be sorted based on the user's requirement.

Comment: @Tim3880 unfortunate it is not static, I'll edit my post. This data can change based on item availability, upper management, etc.

Comment: How are you storing the users' sort preferences?

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot currently, these sort preferences are not implemented. These custom item lists are being created manually by customer service representatives as this is a system that is not implemented.

Comment: You can still use user-based list of pointers for filtering and update the list as needed. If the "data" themselves are changed frequently, caching will not be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to cache the items in a single indexed structure (array, hash table, etc).  Each user maintains a list of keys corresponding to the preferred order in which they'd like to see the items appear (a rinky-dink way to do this is to store a comma-separated string in a single column in the User table) - when you load a user you traverse this list and lookup the items on the cached indexed structure, so creating the sorted list should be an O(n) operation (list traversal instead of sorting).

In the case of "don't know / don't care" items, e.g. items that were added to the cache that the user hasn't assigned a sort preference to yet, you can take the set difference of the keys in the user's preference list and the keys in the cache and add these to the end of the user's preference list; for example, copy all of the keys from the cached indexed structure into a temporary structure in the user's space, as you traverse the user's preference list you remove keys from his temporary structure, and when you've finished traversing the preference list you traverse the temporary structure for any remaining keys and add their corresponding items to the end of the user's list and also add the remaining keys to the end of the user's preference list.